# asp.net 2 GridViews allow drag and drop from source to destination but not vice-versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have two GridViews:

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvCourses" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Course_ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="drag_drop_grid GridSrc"

                                  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                  ShowFooter="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DefaultSlope"/>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <hr/>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvDest" runat="server" CssClass="drag_drop_grid drag_and_drop_grid_sortable GridDest" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DefaultSlope"/>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I am using the following code to drag and drop between them:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".drag_drop_grid").sortable({
        items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        connectWith: '.drag_drop_grid',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        receive: function(e, ui) {
            $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
        },
        sort: function (event, ui) {
            var tdCount = 0;
            ui.item.find('td').each(function () {
                tdCount++;
                if (tdCount > 3)
                    $(this).remove();
            });
        },
        beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            var tdCount = 0;
            ui.item.find('td').each(function () {
                tdCount++;
                if (tdCount > 3)
                    $(this).remove();
            });
        },
        helper: function (e, tr) {
            //copyHelper =
            tr.clone().insertAfter(tr);
            var tdCount = 0;
            tr.find('td').each(function () {
                tdCount++;
                if (tdCount > 3)
                    $(this).remove();
            });
            return tr.clone();
        }
    });
    $("[id*=gvDest] tr:not(tr:first-child)").remove();
});
</script>
```

It works fine but it allows the source gridview to be sorted and records duplicated. In other words, I can drop stuff on that gridview which is not desirable.

It also allows the destination grid to duplicate its own records/table rows.

What do I need to change in my script to:

1. Disallow sorting and dropping on the source grid.
2. Disallow copying from within the destination grid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took more time than I wanted but...

```
   $("#gvCourses tr:not(tr:first-child)").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#gvSelectedCourses',
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    $("#gvSelectedCourses").sortable({
        items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        receive: function (e, ui) {
            sortableIn = 1;
            copyHelper = null;
        },
        beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
            if (sortableIn == 0) {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        },
        over: function (e, ui) { sortableIn = 1; },
        out: function (e, ui) { sortableIn = 0; },
    });
```

The first table -- gvCourses -- is not sortable or droppable nor can it have rows removed and I can drag rows from it to the second table.

The second table -- gvSelectedCourses -- is sortable and droppable and I can remove table rows from it and it can take duplicate rows.